# Neo4j: Using cUrl to execute a query

Tags: rest, curl, neo4j

There are many examples of using cUrl with Neo4j to execute queries but i cannot get it working.
E.g.: https://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/

OS: Windows
DB: Neo4j comunity 3.1.1
cUrl: 7.53.1

```
"D:\Programme\Tools\curl\curl.exe" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"statements":[{"statement":
"match (n) return count(n)"}]}' http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

**Result:**

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message":"Unable to deserialize request: Unexpe
cted character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [
Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@18463df6; line: 1, column: 2]"}]}
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably because you are not passing the username and password of the database within the URL. Try this, it worked on mine:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' http://DB_USERNAME:DB_PASSWORD@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d '{"statements": [{"statement": "MATCH (n) RETURN n;"}]}'
```